# Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary Caching Error in GetCacheManager

Tags: c#, caching, enterprise-library

I am trying to implement enterprise library caching and logging.

I have the latest version (**6.0.1304.0**) of **EnterpriseLibrary.Logging** and   **EnterpriseLibrary.Common**

I have the latest version (**5.0.505.0**) of **EnterpriseLibrary.Caching**

I am getting the below error when I create cache manager`CacheManager cacheManager = (CacheManager)CacheFactory.GetCacheManager();`

[image]

System.TypeLoadException
HResult=0x80131522
Message=Could not load type 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.EnterpriseLibraryContainer' from assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
Source=Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching

**Below is my web.config**

```
 <configSections>
  <section name="cachingConfiguration" 
  
type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.Configuration.CacheManagerSettings, 
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
</configSections>
<cachingConfiguration defaultCacheManager="Default Cache Manager">
    <cacheManagers>
        <add name="Default Cache Manager" expirationPollFrequencyInSeconds="60" 
    maximumElementsInCacheBeforeScavenging="1000" numberToRemoveWhenScavenging="10" 
    backingStoreName="inMemory" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.CacheManager,Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </cacheManagers>
    <backingStores>
        <add name="inMemory" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.BackingStoreImplementations.NullBackingStore, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </backingStores>
</cachingConfiguration>
```

Comment: Anyone can help me with this? CacheManager/CacheFactor everything is using ICacheManager Interface. ICacheManager is using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.EnterpriseLibraryContainer which not available in the latest common library. Which class i can use for Caching?

Answer (score 0):

According Microsoft Learn documentation ([TypeLoadException Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.typeloadexception?view=net-7.0)), this type of exception occurs when the Assembly cannot be found by Common Languange Runtime; like documentation, please, check if the Solution library (DLL) reference point to a different version of Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary based on the Web.Config, this maybe the root-cause.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because both EnterpriseLibrary.Caching and EnterpriseLibrary.Logging both rely internally on EnterpriseLibrary.Common. As both have different versions used here, there is a version conflict for EnterpriseLibrary.Common. There is usually a backward compatibility but as you are trying to use different versions, it is trying to find version 6.0.1304.0 for EnterpriseLibrary.Common version instead of 5.0.xxx version somewhere internally. I think using 5.0.xxx versions for EnterpriseLibrary.Logging and EnterpriseLibrary.Common should ideally resolve the issue here.

Comment: I am using the latest Ent libraries for caching, logging and common. my issue is not version conflict or config issue. I am stuck up with implementing the caching with CacheManager with latest common library. Since latest common library has not the EnterpriseLibraryContainer.